# Stash lists with a dynamic list name in a relationship loop

Tags: stash, relationships

I have got a bunch of entries in this relationship and i want to spit them out and group them by day. So, i thought i could use Stash to capture this, group them into a list for each day and the below is my sorry effort.

It does work, but it's not appending the row of data, it's only ever one row as i guess it's creating and destroying those lists over and over. I can't see any other way to do this though. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
{parents field="products-lessons-pool"}
   {exp:stash:set_list name='{parents:products-lessons-day}' parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site"}

      {stash:class}{parents:products-lessons-class:title}{/stash:class}
      {stash:time}{parents:products-lessons-time format="%g:%i %a"}{/stash:time}
      {stash:day}{parents:products-lessons-day}{/stash:day}
      {stash:entry_id}{parents:entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
      {stash:price}{parents:product_price}{/stash:price}

    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/parents}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh silly me, i had the answer in a code sample on my machine already :-/

```
{parents field="products-lessons-pool"}
      {exp:stash:append name="Monday" match="#Mon#" against="{parents:products-lessons-day}" parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site" refresh="86400"}
            <tr>
                <td>{parents:products-lessons-class:title}</td>
                <td>{parents:products-lessons-time format="%g:%i %a"}</td>
                <td><a href="/cart_functions/add_to_cart/{parents:entry_id}" class="button success radius">Buy</a><br />
                     {parents:product_price}
                 </td>
            </tr>
       {/exp:stash:append}
 {/parents}
```